# Blender 2.8 Topbar

Tags: interface

any ideas why the top bar is gone in the latest Blender 2.8 build from today:

[image: Blen]

Comment: Because Blender 2.80 is still in beta state and things get moved around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you maybe inadvertently close it with the Show Header Checkbox?
[image: Show Header]

If so, bring it back with the tiny arrow at the top right.
[image: Header Toggle]

Only saying this because mine still shows on startup.

Comment: I think you are referring to an older version.

Comment: Downloaded it this morning: 2019-05-07 19:17 Hash:3dc9da3a74ee

Comment: Ok, got it and it is there again, thx!

Comment: Mine is active at startup. When I right-click it, I get the above menu that allows me to disable it and the pull-arrow appears. This might be related to my startup file. Have you tried it with a file from a previous version?

Answer (score 4):

Top bar is now removed from the top in 2.80. It seems developers assessed user feedback and decided it was not very good use of space at the top of the main window because of the small amount of settings/options most tools have. The functionality of the bar has been moved to individual editors as Tool Settings bar.

Comment: You can see some explanation here as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM3FU0m_R4k&feature=youtu.be&t=155

Comment: Alright, I see, thx m8!

Comment: It's back, see post from @Ben

Comment: Pablo actually mentions this in the video linked above, around 07:00

Comment: You are right, it is there already. It is not 'back' though, it is in a different place and  it's not 'the top bar' any more. It is tool settings now. I wouldn't be surprised if it keeps changing a bit in the near future.

Comment: Moved goalposts again.  Now in "Tool" tab of N panel

Comment: I think it is there in addition. It is everywhere now. There is a tab in the Properties editor as well.